# Cleanly Validating Input

Tags: c, validation, input

In talking about "clean code", we typically hear that a cleanly written function does *only one thing*.

When it comes to handling user input, does it count as part of that *one thing* to validate the input? For example,

```
/* Arg1 is passed directly from user input */
int foo(int arg1) {
    if (!arg1 || arg1 < 500) {
        return -1;
    }

    /* Do foo */
}
```

Is it best to write these validation tests inside the function, or should they be separated somehow, as in:

```
if (argIsValid(arg1)) {
    foo(arg1);
}
```

Whatever the case, I would like to hear supporting reasoning with your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *best to write the validation logic in a function* with a name `validate_args()` for example.

You see, when you want to enhance the validation logic, it will obvious were you have to look too, even if you are not the author of the code, so +1 for maintenance!

Moreover, it makes the code more elegant too!

Comment: So would it be more appropriate to call the validation function inside of foo(), or should it be called before foo() is handed the argument?

Comment: Both are OK. In your question you follow the latter. However, **I** would call it inside of `foo()` and if the validation fails, then `foo()` should also fail, i.e. returning an error code, so that the caller (e.g. `main()`) knows that `foo()` didn't terminate successfully. @frog nice question however, I had that from the very start!